# Swipe and click on links with Hammer js

Tags: javascript, css, angular, dom, hammer.js

I have **Angular 12** application.

There is **carousel** with images, which are **links**.
I integrated Hammer JS as expected:

```js
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';

export class HammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = {
    swipe: { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL },
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
      useClass: HammerConfig,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I apply Hammer **event handlers** on the **Carousel wrapper** element like this:

```html
<div
  class="slides"
  (swipeleft)="swipeLeft($event)"
  (swiperight)="swipeRight($event)"
  (tap)="tap($event)"
  [style.touch-action]="'pan-y'"
>
```

And here comes the issue. Trying to swipe a link leads to default dragging behavior.
The image is also causing similar default dragging behavior.
A fix for that is to add css rule for both `<img>` and `<a>` dom elements:

```css
img, a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The swipe functionality for swiping the Carousel panes is working
but now the click/tap event is not working because of `pointer-events: none;`

I know that there is Hammer configuration with the following interface:

```js
class HammerGestureConfig {
  events: string[]
  overrides: {...}
  options?: {...}
  buildHammer(element: HTMLElement): HammerInstance
}
```

**My questions is**: is it possible by applying specific configuration and css rules
to have both swiping and clicking/tapping over link panes of the Carousel?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would it be possible to apply `[ngStyle]` where `pointer-events` is none if not swiped and after swipe is done turn `pointer-events` back to auto?

Comment: Hi Joosep.P I thought already about some toggle class functionality. I have to check but swipe is executed at the end of the event. So, for this, I might need to replace the swipe with pan event (maybe). But still it will be not so reliable I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is not so relevant, but still it is a solution for this case.

So, as quick summary of the case:

-1- I have an image carousel. 
-2- I want to **swipe** the carousel horizontally. 
-3- I want to **scroll** the page vertically event if I place the "finger" over the carousel. 
-4- I want to click/tap over some carousel pane and navigate the link dedicated link.

The **issue** was with the **4-th** point.
In order to have swipe over **link/images**, I had to apply `css` rule:

```css
img, a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

And that was preventing the navigation when the **pane/link/image** is clicked.

So, one solution is to trigger **programmatic navigation** in angular using:

```js
this.router.navigate(['some_route'])
// or
this.router.navigateByUrl('/some_route')
```

Of course, the information is obtained on `tap event` with `event.target` information.
Of course there might be other, more smart solutions. But, at least, this approach is working in very consistent way.